# How to append items from JSON dictionary and modify its structure to form a geoJSON dictionary acceptable in GIS software?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, geojson

so it seems like a basic Python question and I assume it's a matter of placing some brackets in a proper place but anyway I've been sturggling for a while now without success.

I have a number of JSON files, each of them containing a series of features (2 in the example below) with their geometry and properties described in a format like this:

```
{ 
    "version": '1.0',
    "properties": [
        {
            "a":1,
            "b":2,
            "c":3,
            "coordinates": [0, 10]
        },
        {
            "a":4,
            "b":5,
            "c":6,
            "coordinates": [10,20]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, the geoJSON has its structure predefined and I would like to get an output like this:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [

    {"type":"Feature",
    "properties":{
        "a":1,
        "b":2,
        "c":3,
        "coordinates": [0, 10]
      },
    "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[0,10]}},

    {"type":"Feature",
    "properties":{
        "a":2,
        "b":3,
        "c":4,
        "coordinates": [10, 20]
      },
    "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[10,20]}}
        ]
}
```

The code below does the job but the `for loop` when iterating over objects from the original JSON file, overwrites the previous one instead of appending a new feature:

```
f = open(file)
data = json.load(f)

geojson = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': [{'type':'Feature',
                 'properties': {},
                  'geometry': {'type': 'Point',
                               'coordinates': []}
                }]
}

for object in data['properties']:
  geojson['features'][0]['properties'] = object
  geojson['features'][0]['geometry']['type'] = 'Point'
  geojson['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'] = [object['coordinates'][0], object['coordinates'][1]]

with open(processed_file, 'a') as f:
json.dump(geojson, f, indent=2)
```

I am aware what is the problem here but don't know how to make it work. If I move the `with open` and `dump` inside the `for` loop, then the output json file will contain two completely separate features, rather than one common dictionary with only different objects within 'features' key.

I am feeling dumb but got really stuck. Would appreciate your help!

Take care,

Jakub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is close. The only real thing is that you likely want to append your properties into the features rather than set them by index:

```py
data = { 
    "version": '1.0',
    "properties": [
        {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "coordinates": [0, 10]},
        {"a":4, "b":5, "c":6, "coordinates": [10,20]}
    ]
}

geojson = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': []
}

for property in data['properties']:
    geojson['features'].append(
        {
            'type':'Feature',
            'properties': property,
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': [
                    property['coordinates'][0],
                    property['coordinates'][1]
                ]
            }
        }
    )

import json
print(json.dumps(geojson, indent=4))
```

That should give you:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "a": 1,
                "b": 2,
                "c": 3,
                "coordinates": [
                    0,
                    10
                ]
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    0,
                    10
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "a": 4,
                "b": 5,
                "c": 6,
                "coordinates": [
                    10,
                    20
                ]
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    10,
                    20
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: OMG thanks! I knew that it would be something simple! It works perfectly :)